# Optimized ping with threads in ruby, possible?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ping

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and I cannot upgrade to 1.9+ anytime soon.

I understand that ruby has green threads, and anything cpu based does not gain much by way of multithreading.

However, I was trying a multithreaded ping in ruby, as in my script will try to ping N machines in the network -- in the time a machine replies back there's enough time to create a new thread and initiate connection with another host. However what I see is that multithreading has actually worsened performance.

Any suggestions to do an optimized ping with threads in ruby?

Comment: How is the pinging implemented? Perhaps there is some sort of global interpreter lock which is affecting performance? Also you might try JRuby, if you can..it has a better thread implementation.

Comment: @Casper -- how do I know if there is some global interpreter lock being used here?

Comment: There is no way to know without looking at the code and analyzing each part and trying to figure out how they interact. That's why I was curious if you could post some snippet of how you actually do the pinging, and maybe we can see if there is some issue there.

Comment: The global interpreter lock is part of Ruby 1.9 and is explained in section 2.3 (Threading Model) of this document:  http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf

Comment: How about just opening up a pipe to `fping`?

Comment: @user5402 could you please elaborate? What does opening the pipe do?

Comment: @Frantic look up the docs for `IO.popen`

Comment: Have you looked up process forking? This may better suit your needs. See method #3 on this link. It removes the issue of the interpreter lock and many of the hassles of multithreading. You can use the database or TCP to communicate between processes if necessary: http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) with an [ICMP implementation](https://github.com/jakedouglas/icmp4em). The author of icmp4em also provides two examples how to use all this stuff.